# Mongodb or mongoose performance issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I developed an application that backed up with nodeJs/mongodb and frontend is in Angularjs 1.6.5. Application is used to provide realtime analytics and data is being increased in size every single minute with new data.

As the database size is increasing, queries are taking much longer time to execute and even sometime fails and giving 404 error. (Nginx server) But the strange thing is that whenever i ran the same query in mongo shell in server with .explain('executionStats') method its giving immediate responses with execution time 0 millisecond.

[image: Query on Mongo Shell]

[image: Execution on browser]

[image: execution with no limit]

So as per above screenshots, with limit of 10 data mongo shell executing it in no time but in browser when i am hitting the db through node and mongoose it took 1 min but couldn't possible return the result (maybe nginx returning 404 after specif time)

but i try in mongo shell after that without setting up any limit that also returning data with 6331522 records in less then 4 seconds.

I have no clue what is the issue exactly. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: It depends on how exactly you're running the queries in Node. Also, NGINX returning a 404 in case of timeouts doesn't make a lot of sense (unless it's specifically configured to return a 404 instead of something like a 502 or 503).

Comment: Also your "screenshots" ( which are oddly taken from a terminal with "text" output ) clearly show `COLSCAN` in the execution. Which essentially mean no index is being selected. In real world applications you are going to need "indexes", and it would appear that you presently have none that suit the query selections. So the very first thing to do is look at the queries you are issuing, work out which criteria effects the selection the most and then add indexes to those fields as are commonly used in the common query selections.

Comment: @NeilLunn wouldn't a collection scan be reasonable if you're basically retrieving all documents?

Comment: @robertklep It's not a very realistic assessment though. "Does a database take time to work out how to retrieve the whole collection?" Well yes, I think most people would agree it does. "Is this a realistic indicator of what an application needs to do?" Then the answer is no. As far as I can tell the "phrasing" of the question is *"Is this a performance bug?"*. So the answer is like most "bug" reports, is the "bug" lies more in the understanding than the service/library used.

Comment: @NeilLunn from what I understand, they find that running a "return all documents" (or "return 10 documents") query is extremely slow compared to running the same query from the Mongo shell, so I guess they want to find out what the difference is that makes the Node code so much slower.

Comment: Exactly @robertklep query from shell is taking very few time but from node/mongoose it doesn't even able to execute. 

Is there anything i did wrong here ?

Comment: @sarabs3 without posting your code we have no idea. Also, I'm not sure if the Mongo shell isn't timing how long it takes to return a _cursor_, as opposed to the actual result _documents_. Big difference.

Comment: @robertklep http://prntscr.com/g0xk3k here is the snapshot of the code. It is  identical to the query i am writing to the mongo shell.